# How to use grpc streaming in grpc-web?

Tags: grpc, grpc-web

I want to send files to server from React client. I know that for this I should use grpc streaming and split files into chunks. So, the question is how to send these chunks to server?

Answer (score 2):

There are some basic tutorials on our Github repo: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web#how-it-works on how to use streaming.

If you need client-side streaming, that is currently not supported. You might want to re-design your RPCs in such a way that you will be sending a bunch of chunks as series of unary calls, and re-assemble the chunks on the server side.